# Scala general performances and code optimization

Tags: performance, scala

What about performance of the compiled code of scala related to normal Java?

And What about the overhead of recursion instead of "the standard for/while loop"? It's less performance?

and if Yes,  what are the trade off of losing performance?

**EDIT**

The Answer gave me from Andreas Neumann was almost of I wanted to know. Just missing:

*When It's better use Scala instead of Java.*

**Narrowing the question:**
When Scala it would preferred for a consistent project instead of Java, or is it better a mix of both?

I don't know, just guessing, maybe for code maintainability?

Comment: This question is currently too broad.  Like any language, the performance of Scala depends on how the code sample being benchmarked has been written.  In general Scala is very fast, and can be very fast.  That said I also know other companies who get very poor performance because of the way that they write their code.  They would be slow using Java too.  If you can narrow your question to a specific situation, then it will fit the format for stack overflow and we will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A short answer to your Question:**

It depends.

**A longer answer:**

In most cases you would end up with as fast code as you would get with Java. It depends a lot on your coding experience in Java as it does in in Scala.
In a lot of cases the compiler will be able to turn a recursive implementation in a while-loop under the hood -> see @tailrec Annotation for information on that matter.

**A good/scientific answer:**

Here is a good paper on that Question done by Google Research: Loop Recognition in C++/Java/Go/Scala . Take a look at their findings.
Abstract -> http://research.google.com/pubs/pub37122.html
PDF -> http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/de//pubs/archive/37122.pdf